# How to show only time of date in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

Hi All How to show only time value in angular js?

- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PXZk9xQS1NpHxGdCheiA?p=preview)
- I have fetched time value using of `ng-repeat`, and I just want to show only time value in my portal.
- I were tried to fetch time value like `<p>3. TIME</p><span><h4>{{user.time | date:'medium'}}</h4></span>`
- For example:-  Instead of `Jan 1, 1970 10:00:00 PM` i want to show only the time `10:00:00 PM`
- How to do this please help us thanks.

**My Html:-**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <p>1. Name</p><span><h4>{{user.title}}</h4></span>
  <p>2. Day</p><span><h4>{{user.day}}</h4></span>
  <p>3. TIME</p><span><h4>{{user.time | date:'medium'}}</h4></span>
</div>
```

**My Data:-**

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        "_id": "5a33880dd725a05813014c22",
        "user": {
            "_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
            "displayName": "Maniselvam selvam",
            "dob": "1991-05-10T07:00:00.000Z",
            "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/a7d398db972da9dcb1c90480353d00c0"
        },
        "__v": 2,
        "openeyers": [],
        "time": "1970-01-01T16:30:00.000Z",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "registration_number": "Test3",
        "title": "Mercy",
        "created": "2017-12-15T08:30:05.357Z",
        "isCurrentUserOwner": true
    }
]
```

Comment: You can use **{{user.time | date:'hh:mm'}}** to get only the time..

Comment: `'h:mm:ss a'` because OP also requested seconds and AM/PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
{{user.time | date:'medium'}}
```

use

```
{{user.time | date:'mediumTime'}}
```

It's [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

> 'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' for en_US locale (e.g. 12:05:08 PM)